# how can i append a value to a list inside a tuple in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

For example, if I have a list of tuples such as 
`[("a1", ["a2", "a3"]), ("b1", ["b2", "b3"])]`
and I want to add `a4` using `a1` & `a4` as an input to update the list so that we get 
`[("a1", ["a2", "a3", "a4"]), ("b1", ["b2", "b3"])]` as an output, how would I go about approaching this? I know that we can't literally "update" a tuple, and that I have to make an entirely new list

Comment: This kind of modification operations over structures are nicely generalized by the [Lens package](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial). Also [this very recent book](https://leanpub.com/optics-by-example) seems to be very informative on the optics topic in Haskell.

Comment: Updated the title: you are trying to add to a *list* inside a tuple, which means creating a new list with one new tuple (and `n` - 1 preexisting tuples) with a new list inside it.

Comment: There is probably a solution using the `lens` package that lets you write something like `[...] ? "a1" ? "a4"`, where the `?` are various operators that look more like line noise than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this function using recursion:

```hs
updateValueUsingKey :: Eq a => a -> b -> [(a, [b])] -> [(a, [b])]
updateValueUsingKey a b ((a',bs):abs)
    | a == a'   = (a',bs++[b]):abs                       -- update value if found
    | otherwise = (a',bs) : updateValueUsingKey a b abs  -- otherwise keep on recursing
updateValueUsingKey a b [] = []                          -- end the recursion if no more elements
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot mutate a List (updating existing elements) then fmap it.

If you cannot mutate a List (shrinking or expanding) then bind it.

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
-- lookup will scan the List of Tuples for the Key
-- Use Maybe since You dont know the Key you are looking may Exist or not
updateValueUsingKey :: Eq a => a -> b -> [(a, [b])] -> Maybe [(a, [b])]
updateValueUsingKey key value associatedList = 
    ((++[value]) <$> lookup key associatedList) 
    >>= (\v -> return $ fmap (\p -> if (fst p) == key then (key, v) else p) associatedList)

-- If you know exactly the key exists then use fromJust to extract the Value out of Maybe
updateValueUsingKey' :: Eq a => a -> b -> [(a, [b])] -> [(a, [b])]
updateValueUsingKey' key value associatedList = fromJust $ updateValueUsingKey key value associatedList
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is known as an *association list*: each tuple consists of a name and a value associated with that name. If all you mean to do is look up lists by their "name" (the first element of a tuple), the built-in `lookup` function is sufficient. Since you want to *update* the lists, it would be easier to work with a `Map` instead , which (assuming all the names are unique) can be initialized from your list easily.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

type MyMap = M.Map String [String]

append :: String -> String -> MyMap -> MyMap
append k v = M.insertWith (flip (++)) k [v]
```

The function argument to `insertWith` is called with the new value as its first argument and the existing value as the second. As such, `(++)` alone would *prepend* your new element to the list. Since you want to *append* the new value, use `flip (++)` to reverse the order of the arguments.

For example:

```
> data = M.fromList [("a1", ["a2", "a3"]), ("b1", ["b2", "b3"])]
> data
fromList [("a1",["a2","a3"]),("b1",["b2","b3"])]
> append "a1" "a4" data
fromList [("a1",["a2","a3","a4"]),("b1",["b2","b3"])]
```